# How to have able styles.scss for all application?

Tags: angular, typescript, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I use [NX](https://nx.dev/angular/getting-started/what-is-nx) for combining several angular-projects. I create global `styles.scss` in apps catalog

```
apps
  appName
    src
      styles.scss
libs
  lib1
  lib2
  lib3
```

Styles from styles.scss able in apps catalog, but they are not available in libs catalog. Please help me fix it.

Comment: See `nrwl/nx` feature request: [**allow apps/libs to reference libs styles**](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/54)